# Vb.net loop value stored to an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, for-loop

I have the following code which loop through all the cells of the selected row. How to store all the values in an array?

```
Dim selectedCellCount As Integer = dgvData.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    Dim RowVal As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To selectedCellCount - 1
        RowVal = dgvData.SelectedCells(i).Value.ToString
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a class and add the class to a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two method one with list another with array

> 1- List

```
Dim selectedCellCount As Integer = dgvData.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
Dim RowVal As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim list As New List(Of string)
For i = 0 To selectedCellCount - 1
    RowVal = dgvData.SelectedCells(i).Value.ToString
    list.Add(RowVal)
Next i
End Sub
```

> 2- Array

```
Dim selectedCellCount As Integer = dgvData.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
Dim RowVal As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrayOfData(selectedCellCount - 1) As String
For i = 0 To selectedCellCount - 1
    RowVal = dgvData.SelectedCells(i).Value.ToString
    arrayOfData(i) = RowVal
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You should set the array size to `selectedCellCount - 1` instead of `10`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out a List(of string). The list is easier to use than any other type of array. Here is a good explanation:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-vbnet